# Average days between 2 dates columns R

Tags: r, date, datetime, statistics

I have 2 dates columns in a dataframe with more than 100k observations

| date1 | startdate |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-07-30 23:00:00 | NA |
| 2020-12-10 04:00:00 | 2021-06-30 20:00:00 |
| 2020-10-26 21:00:00 | NA |
| 2019-12-03 03:01:00 | 2020-02-01 01:00:00 |
| NA | 2020-06-28 07:30:00 |

I have to fill the missing values in startdate column, so my idea is to compute the average of days between date1 and startdate and to replace the NA in startdate after by doing an addition between this average and the date1 date.

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

For instance, if the average of days is 70, then :

| date1 | startdate |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-07-30 23:00:00 | 2020-10-08 23:00:00 |
| 2020-12-10 04:00:00 | 2021-06-30 20:00:00 |
| 2020-10-26 21:00:00 | 2021-01-04 21:00:00 |
| 2019-12-03 03:01:00 | 2020-02-01 01:00:00 |
| NA | 2020-06-28 07:30:00 |

Reproducible example :

> structure(list(date1 = structure(c(1594069500,
> 1575320400, 1603742400, NA, 1574975100, 1570845660, 1575061500,
> 1564714860, 1576544400, 1574802300, 1576198800, 1575338460, 1575666180,
> NA, 1594327800, 1595365200, 1594069800, 1591905600, 1594414800,
> NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), startdate = structure(c(1599242400,
> 1577127600, NA, 1603396800, 1577516400, 1573714800, 1577689200,
> 1566374400, 1577343600, 1577516400, 1577343600, NA, 1577257200,
> NA, 1605193200, 1605106800, 1600358400, 1600358400, 1600272000,
> NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(1L,
> 2L, 7591L, 8301L, 8692L, 8694L, 8699L, 8703L, 8706L, 8709L, 8710L,
> 8714L, 8715L, 8730L, 8732L, 8733L, 8736L, 8740L, 8745L, 8749L
> ), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `difftime` to calculate average duration between `startdate` and `date1`. Replace `NA` values in `startdate` by adding the average value to `date1`.

```
avg <- as.numeric(mean(difftime(df$startdate, df$date1, units = 'secs'), na.rm = TRUE))
df$startdate[is.na(df$startdate)] <- df$date1[is.na(df$startdate)] + avg
df
```

Comment: The value of avg on my full data is NaN. Do you know where it can comes from since we use na.rm=T ?

Comment: You can check couple of things. 1) In your real dataset are the column names called `startdate` and `date1` or are they named something else? 2) Is one of the column always `NA` ?

Comment: i renamed the columns in the code in the right way before executing and none of my columns is always NA

Comment: no in fact you were right, in this sample both columns are never filled at the same time my bad.

Answer (score 0):

something like this??
I cannot verify, since your desired output does not match your sample data..

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)
mydata[is.na(startdate) & !is.na(date1), 
       startdate := date1 + round(mean(abs(DT$date1 - DT$startdate), na.rm = TRUE))]
```